# Function giving the y-th digit of x represented in base n

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Euler's formula

> $$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$

is famous because it combines

- five constants: $e, i, \pi, 1, 0$
- four operations: exponentation, multiplication, addition, equality

The following function is probably not as famous as Euler's equation, even though it is of comparable importance: $\omega(x,y,n) := x / n^y\ \text{mod}\ n $:

> $$x / n^y\ \text{mod}\ n $$

It combines three operations: division, exponentation and modulo and gives the $y$-th digit of $x$ represented in base $n$.

My questions are:

- Does this function already have a common name?
- If not so, wouldn't be "Leibniz' function" be appropriate, because Leibniz was such an early advocate of the binary system?

Comment: Respectfully, I would strongly disagree that anything to do with digits is of comparable importance to $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ (which itself is just a less natural variation of $e^{\tau i}=1$).

Comment: On a separate note, your formula doesn't seem to take into account that you also must throw out any fractional part of $\frac{x}{n^y}$.

Comment: The invention of binary encoding - let it be by nature or by Leibniz - has been of huge importance, I guess.